# Weight Attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have recently removed weight attribute from my attribute sets (there were products that had weight set) after I included weight attribute again weight does not save, acutally it does save in the database but after editing products it is always empty or has an old value, this is very important to me since I calculate shiping based on weight. It actually seems like it does save the value to the database but doesnt load it on product  edit page. One more thing is that newly added products do not have this issue....

I was wondering if anyone had the same issute maybe with different attribute other than weight as in my case.

Any help is appreciated

I do need the weight attribute for shipping calculation and I have tried to edit the attribute in the admin panel (ofcourse it was not possible to save it) maybe this did manage to save something to the database and screwed it up....

**EDIT**

Actually weight wont save on a configurable product but works correctly on its child simple products and other products

Thanks

Comment: cleared the cache? Reindexed? Any Coderelated stuff? Addons which store additional values?

Comment: *"I have recently removed weight attribute from my attribute sets"* **How did you do this? Admin panel? Script?** *"I included weight attribute again"* **How did you do this? Admin panel? Script?**

Comment: tried everything cache, reindexing etc.. the attribut was removed and moved back to my attribute set via admin panel.. I am not a newbie, but this is one of those problems which are incosistent, appear irregulary, i simply cant pinpoint it... thanks

Comment: Actually weight wont save on a configurable product but works correctly on its child simple products and other products

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: First remove it again from Attribute Set. Then clean the cache, reindex. After that, add it again. Clean the cache, reindex. Check then. Also, check the options for the attribute weight, for which kind of products should be visible.